# pandas convert groupby values to column names

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas table where I have many lines with loan maturity year (can have multiple loans for any given year), loan notional, and loan type (fixed rate/floating rate).

I want to extract the debt tower of a company into the a dataframe table which looks like:

Year, FixedRate, FloatingRate 
2018, sumofallfixed loans, sumofallfloatloans   for the given year.

MaturityYear      Type  Notional (MM) 
0          2020     FIXED          600.0 
1          2021     FIXED          750.0 
2          2021  FLOATING          250.0 
3          2025     FIXED          700.0

to convert into 
Year, FIXED, FLOAT 
2020,   600,    0 
2021,   750,    250 
2025   700,     0

How can I do this with pandas?

Many thanks,
Toni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum`, last reshape by `unstack`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Year', 'LoanType'])['loan notional'].sum().unstack()
```

Comment: this doesn't add columns for total fixed and total float rate maturing this year. It gives the sum both for the given year. 

I want to convert the groupby ['Year', 'LoanType'] into loan type being columns

Comment: OK, can you add data sample to question, 4-5 rows and desired ouput?

Comment: just added an edit to my post with sample data. Let me check if your update works.

Comment: YESS, This work perfectly! thanks, I will like the comment when the minimum required time passes!

Answer (score 3):

Heres a pivot solution i.e

```
df.pivot(index='Year',columns='Type',values='Notional(MM)').fillna(0)
```

```
Type  FIXED  FLOATING
Year                 
2020  600.0       0.0
2021  750.0     250.0
2025  700.0       0.0
```

If needed sum i.e

```
df.pivot_table(index='Year',columns='Type',values='Notional(MM)',aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `pd.crosstab`, also, `pivot` can achieve this too :-)

```
pd.crosstab(index =df['MaturityYear'],columns =df['Type'],values =df['Notional'],aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
Out[877]: 
Type          FIXED  FLOATING
MaturityYear                 
2020          600.0       0.0
2021          750.0     250.0
2025          700.0       0.0
```